# Clearing a sprite instead of using clear()

Tags: c, graphics

I'm writing a game and I need to move a sprite around. I am drawing the sprite, updating the new location, redrawing it, and clearing the last iteration of the sprite, thereby making it look like it's moving.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble actually clearing the previous iteration of the sprite from the screen.

```
void move_sprite() {//this is used in a while loop within the main

        get_direction();//just checks to see which direction the dx/dy should move in
        clear_sprite(sprite.x, sprite.y, width, height);//should clear the previous iteration of the sprite
        update_sprite(&sprite);//modifies the x/y dx/dy of the sprite, moving it
        draw_sprite(&sprite);//this just draws the sprite at whatever coordinate update_sprite tells it to move to, it is moving one pixel at a time.
        refresh();
        _delay_ms( 200 );

}

void clear_sprite(unsigned char x, unsigned char y, const int width, const int height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < height; ii++){
            set_pixel(x + i, y + ii, 0);
        }
    }   
}
```

It goes through both the x and y of the 3 x 3 sprite and sets each pixel value to 0, thereby clearing it on the LCD screen. However the previous iteration of the drawn sprite stays, resulting in an unwanted "trailing" effect.

Comment: Are you using a particular framework? What platform is this for? Your question is far too vague for us to answer. Please add more information.

Comment: It looks like sprite is global and probably being update in your event handler before clearsprite() runs.  Or possibly in getdirection()